# How qml WebSocket uses Sec-Websocket-Key

Tags: qt, qml

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebsockets-websocket.html#errorString-prop

In this website, I did not find **Sec-Websocket-Key** and **Sec-Websocket-Protocol** and other related settings.

How can I use them in qml?

Do I need to use C++ **QWebsocket**?

Comment: Thank you. I understand. As far as I know, **Sec-Websocket-Protocol** is in the **Header**, but I can modify it to the **url**.

Comment: Let me correct my previous comment: 1) Qt WebSocket does not support WebSocket Subprotocols/Sec-Websocket-Protocol, [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebsocket.html#details): *QWebSocket currently does not support WebSocket Extensions and WebSocket Subprotocols.*, 2) by default "Sec-Websocket-Key" is randomly generated, docs: *Warning: To generate masks, this implementation of WebSockets uses the reasonably secure QRandomGenerator::global()->generate() function* although it can be modified. 3) With the above you could explain what you want to do.